Equidistribution of orbits.
Here is a question I am thinking about:
Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Show that if $(X,T,\mu)$ is an ergodic topological probability measure preserving dynamical system and $x \in X$ is generic, then for any open set $U$ with measure zero boundary, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\# \{k| 1 \leq k \leq n, T^k(x) \in U\}}{n} = \mu(U).$$
Some thoughts:
If I know that for any compact set $K,$ there is a collection of continuous functions $f_n: X \to [0,1]$ such that $$\chi_K \leq f_n \leq f_{n-1}$$ where $\chi_X$ is the indicator function on $K,$ and such that for any Borel probability measure $\mu,$ we have $$\mu(K) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_Xf_n d\nu.$$
What will this tell me about $\bar{U}$? What about $U$?
Could someone clarify to me this points and give me more intuition and insight towards solving the problem?

Since $\partial U$ has measure zero, $\mu(\overline U)=\mu(U)$ and so given $\varepsilon>0$, there are continuous functions
$$
f<\chi_U\le\chi_{\overline U}< g
$$
such that $\int_X(g-f)\,d\mu<\varepsilon$. Note that
$$
\int_Xf\,d\mu\le\mu(U)\le\int_Xg\,d\mu.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(T^k(x))\le\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\# \{k| 1 \leq k \leq n, T^k(x) \in U\}}{n}\le\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g(T^k(x))
$$
for $\mu$-almost every $x$,
which is the same as
$$
\int_Xf\,d\mu\le\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\# \{k| 1 \leq k \leq n, T^k(x) \in U\}}{n}\le\int_Xg\,d\mu
$$
for $\mu$-almost every $x$, because of ergodicity. Letting $\varepsilon\to0$ yields that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\# \{k| 1 \leq k \leq n, T^k(x) \in U\}}{n}=\mu(U)
$$
for $\mu$-almost every $x$ (of course also for generic points).

Are you saying that the first inequality line in my thoughts should be adjusted?

If you can use, fine. I can't. Note that you need to approximate from both sides.

can not the indicator function just be the limit?

I don't follow what you mean. You need to approximate from both sides, and what you wrote only gives an approximation from above!

Why we need to approximate from both sides?

Because $a\le b$ does not imply that $a=b$. As I mentioned before: I can't use it, but maybe it's me. Anyways, I don't understand why you want to use something that you don't know whether it can be used to prove what you want to prove... Did someone tell you that it's enough?

Yeah I had a discussion about this with one of my colleagues and they told me it is enough.

That's good, so please ask your colleague to add the argument here. Of course, you can also add it yourself.

Obviously not, please give full details.
